# To separate the doc in an different repository or not?

Tags: python-sphinx

I wonder how people are handling the repository of the documentation of their modules (I am mostly doing python/sphinx/git).

Facing two choices:

1. include the doc sources in the module repository

   has the advantage of having a all in one unique place for the project, but the inconvenience of bringing non-vital data with the code (for instance images for the doc)
2. make a separate repository for the documentation

   has the advantage of having a separate life cycle between the doc and the module code. When correcting a doc typo for instance one would like to avoid a new repository version for the code. The drawback is to maintain two repositories with maybe equivalent branching.

Are there clear guidelines somewhere? Am I missing some important points?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Git specifically: the same questions would apply regardless of version control system. I suspect it's a matter of opinion though.

Comment: The question does not have much to do with Sphinx either. It could just as well be about Doxygen or Asciidoctor or some other documentation tool.

Comment: myproject is the root directory. Inside that is `src`, `docs`, and `tests`. Inside `src` is the source code of your package. Only the package gets released. Take a look at how Pyramid does it: https://github.com/pylons/pyramid